# Calculating the Sum of Squares in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having issues calculating the sum of squares in javascript. I get lost when I define the for the loop and the variable index. Can anyone help me understand what i am doing wrong?

```
var sums = [];
var sumsqs= Number(prompt("Please enter a number to sum the square"));
for (var index = 0; index < sumsqs.length; index++) {
var total = total + sumsqs[index] * sumsqs[index];

document.write("<h1>The sum of squares is " + total + ".</h1>");
```

Thank you,
Viv

Comment: rather than post on SO, for this kind of obvious issue you should console.log each var to watch their content.

Comment: @GameAlchemist This is not how you debug JavaScript. You should set a breakpoint in a browser's devtools, the you'll be able to check all local and global variables at once.

Comment: console.log is just right for such a simple case, faster than debug - you see that sumsqs is not an array and you're done -.   
So yes for more complex matters, using devTool is most useful, but i didn't find relevant to talk about devTool to someone not indenting, declaring the var in the loop, using document.write, and failing to sum some squares.

Answer (score 5):

If you’re looking to convert, say, a comma-separated list of numbers to an array of numbers, that is not

```
Number(prompt("Please enter a number to sum the square"))
```

(which will attempt to convert the entire string to a number), but rather

```
prompt("Please enter a number to sum the square").split(",").map(Number)
```

You also can’t declare and start to use `total` at the same time; you’ll get NaN. Declare and initialize it before the loop:

```
var total = 0;

for (var index = 0; index < sumsqs.length; index++) {
    total += sumsqs[index] * sumsqs[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputNumber = Number(prompt("Please enter a number to sum the square"));
document.write("<h1>The sum of squares is " +
   ((inputNumber * (inputNumber + 1) * (2 * inputNumber + 1))/6) + ".</h1>");
```

It uses the formula mentioned here to calculate the result. http://library.thinkquest.org/20991/gather/formula/data/209.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone feedback. I just saw it a little too late. Here's what I did to complete the assignment. I was able to figure it out with help of web console.

Thanks again!

```
var sumsqs = [];
    var sumsq = Number(prompt("Please enter a number to calculate the sum the square or -1 to stop"));
    while (sumsq != -1) {
    sumsqs.push(sumsq);
      sumsq = Number(prompt("Please enter a number to calculate the sum the square or -1 to stop"));
    }

    var total_sumsqs = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < sumsqs.length; index++) {
    total_sumsqs = total_sumsqs + sumsqs[index] * sumsqs[index];
    }

    document.write("<h3>The sum of squares is " + total_sumsqs + ".</h3>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the sum of squares of a comma-separated list using the following expression:

```
Math.hypot(...prompt().split`,`)**2
```

**Explanation:**

`` ...prompt().split`,` `` accepts user input and creates an array from the input using `,` as the delimiter. Then the elements of the result array are converted to arguments for `Math.hypot()` using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_function_calls).

[`Math.hypot()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) returns the square root of the sum of squares of its arguments, so if you raise the result to the power of `2` using the [exponentiation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)), you can obtain the sum of squares.